Is the "you" in "you may be perfect and complete" (James 1:4) meant as a group or as an individual?
When editing this question I just realized that the OP understood the "you" in James 1:2-4 (ESV)

Count it all joy, my brothers, when you meet trials of various kinds, for you know that the testing of your faith produces steadfastness. And let steadfastness have its full effect, that you may be perfect and complete, lacking in nothing.

as plural (learning and growing in suffering together), which made me think that since James definitely started with a plural "my brothers" that he may also meant the plural "you" in "you meet trials ...", "you know that ...", "testing of your faith ..." and "you may be perfect ...".  That is, James meant "perfect and complete" as a group (local church?) rather than strictly as an individual Christian.  Or maybe James meant both, with 2 related meanings.
Some evidence for plurality which may have been intended by James:

Other significant passages that have even more obvious communal connotation of the community suffering together include 1 Pet 1:6-9 & 1 Pet 4:12-19, John 16:33, and Rom 8:18-25.

As Paul emphasizes in 1 Cor 12:12-26, there is unity yet diversity in the Body.

Eph 4:25-27: That Christ gave himself for the church to make her holy so that he present the church (the Body of Christ) to himself in splendor (which recalls the "perfect and complete" in James 1:4)

Luke Timothy Johnson in his Catholic-tinged Anchor Yale commentary (1995) on 1:2-8:

of your faith: Notice the plural pronoun: not only the virtue of the individual, but the character of the entire community is at stake.  Nor is it aretē ("virtue") that is proven, but rather pistis ("faith").  This is the first of fourteen instances of the term pistis in James.  In the present case, it denotes, at least, a human attitude or commitment that both can be threatened and can grow.  In the broadest terms, this can be understood as a kind of aretē, but one that also defines the community of readers' ēthos.



We modern Western Evangelicals tend to think individualistically, so I want to revisit how the original audience of this letter might have understood "you may be perfect and complete".  Was it plural or singular?  Was it both (with 2 related meanings)?
It would be great if the answer could provide not only Greek grammar analysis of this passage, but also the theological context of the letter.

First the easy part - "you" in James 1:4 does not exist in the original Greek - it is implied by the plural verb.  That implied second person pronoun is plural.
Second, the tricky part.  That fact that James is writing in the plural does not necessarily mean that he is addressing the group as a whole - he could simply be addressing the church members as group but intend the message to be taken individually.  The answer lies in the context.
Now, there is no such thing as collective faith - all faith and trust is individual - we do not arrive in heaven as a result of a collective faith - we need individual trust in God.
Look at V2-4 -

2 Consider it pure joy, my brothers, when you encounter trials of many kinds, 3 because you know that the testing of your faith
develops perseverance. 4 Allow perseverance to finish its work, so
that you may be mature and complete, not lacking anything.

Note the sequence that James outlines:

trials tests our faith
tested faith produces perseverance
perseverance matures and completes us so that we lack nothing

Such a sequence makes no sense for a church corporately, only individually.  However, such maturation best occurs in a group such as the church.  when faith is tested, it is always helpful to have a faith community to help support us through difficult times.  I suspect it is for this reason that Hebrews tells us:

Heb 10:25 - Let us not neglect meeting together, as some have made a
habit, but let us encourage one another, and all the more as you see
the Day approaching.


There are stories from missionaries in other cultures of familes (or even villages) discussing among themselves whether or not they should be Christians, and then making a group decision.   Some even interpret Acts 16:31 in that light.

@WGroleau - that is true - household is still distinct from a whole village.

"there is no such thing as collective faith - all faith and trust is individual" Does this really follow from the context in the Epistle of James (I provided counter evidence in my edited Q), esp. in light of other passages such as Paul's complimenting the Roman church (Rom 1:8) and the Thessalonian church (1 Thess 1:8) for their faith that "is being reported all over the world" or "has become known everywhere".

@GratefulDisciple - all those comments reveal is that those churches had a significant number of people that had great faith.
